# DCOM object - CoCreateInstanceEx succeeds, but Activator.CreateInstance fails

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, dcom

Native C++ code:

```
int main()
{
   auto hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 

   COSERVERINFO server = {0, L"Win7x64", nullptr, 0};

   MULTI_QI qi = {&IID_XXXService, nullptr, 0};

   hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_XXXService, nullptr, CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, &server, 1, &qi);
}
```

Succeeds, with any threading model. With or without a call to `CoInitializeSecurity`.
But when trying to instantiate same object from a .NET/C#, it always fails with `0x80070005`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var machineName = "Win7x64";
    try
    {
        Type dcomType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(typeof(XXXService).GUID, machineName, false);
        object dcomObj = Activator.CreateInstance(dcomType);               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried the latter with `CoInitializeSecurity` (DllImported), with MTA and STA thread attribute, with UAC elevated process, but it always fails. If `machineName` is for current machine, it works (yes, current development machine has same COM interface, and class registered).

EDIT: In order to successfully call `CoInitializeSecurity`, the setting 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' must be disabled. Still then, `CreateInstance` fails.

With native code, it always works. With managed code, it never works. What could be done?

EDIT2: COM security on remote machine:

- Access Permissions (Limits): Everyone, as well as ANONYMOUS LOGON (among other common) - Full access.
- Access Permissions (Default): SELF, SYSTEM, ANONYMOUS LOGON - Full access to all.
- Launch & Activation (Limits): Everyone, DCOM Users, ANONYMOUS LOGON (among other common) - Full access.
- Launch & Activation Permissions (Default): SYSTEM, NETWORK, ANONYMOUS LOGON, INTERACTIVE - Full access to all.

Comment: Try passing `true` as the last arg to `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(typeof(XXXService).GUID, machineName, false)`. Does it throw?

Comment: Tried both, doesn't make any difference. Throw or not throw, it should work. It is anyway failing.

Comment: Do *not* expect anybody to write you the missing manual on DCOM security.  Post your code and carefully describe the account you use and its rights on the remote machine.

Comment: @HansPassant, Updated the security. Question is still the same - why does it work with native code and not from managed world. It has nothing to do with security (at server side).
The code posted is complete.

Comment: The complete lack of error checking and the **required** interface pointer marshaling, always necessary when you use COINIT_MULTITHREADED, does not inspire me to think that your native code works either.  The kind of oversight that the CLR never makes.

Comment: Function call is secondary. Typecasting and marshalling are secondary. Posted minimal understandable code, not a Code-Complete theory. I have posted only after failed attempts, and failed online results.

Comment: @Ajay did you ever get past this? I'm having the same problem.